# How do i display my items in a row ( using php and bootstrap to display all items from a database)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am using php to display the last five events from my database as the most recent events. However the bootstrap along with the css are making them show as a column when i want them displayed 3 to a row instead of going down the page.

I have tried using css flex: row; etc to make it work but im unsure if the bootstrap is messing it up.

I want three cards displaying across the page then the fourth on the next row etc. I have tried using nth child but it doesnt work its reading the each one as the same card instead of different cards. Is there any way round this or anything wrong with my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <link href="css/recentevents.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">


                    <?php


                    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT e.*,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_events WHERE Event_ID = e.Event_ID) AS total_registrations FROM Events e ORDER BY Event_ID DESC LIMIT 0 , 5"); 

                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
                         $event = new Event($row);
                          $today = date("Y-m-d");   
                if($event->status == 'published' and $event->date >= $today){

    ?>

    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4"> 
                <div class="card"> 
                    <?php
                  echo'<img class="card-img-top" data-src=y=d ata-holder-rendered="true" width="600" src="data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['event_image'] ) . '" />'

                      ?>
                    <div class="card-body">     
                        <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $event->title?></h4>     
                        <p class="card-text"><?php echo $event->content?></p>
                        <a href="events_page.php" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</a>   </div> </div> </div>
        </div>
    </div>

      <?php
                }
           }
        ?>

CSS class
    .blank-section {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        margin-top: 15PX;
    }
    .card {
        position: relative;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        min-width: 0;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-clip: border-box;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
        border-radius: .25rem;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
```

I am meant to see the cards displayed about three in a row however they just keep displaying down the ways.

It works for the code below it belongs to a different part of my website:
It works for the piece of code below but i need it for the one above

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM feedback");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
 echo "  <div class=\"reviews\">\n";
echo "  <div class=\"row blockquote review-item\">\n";
echo "   <div class=\"col-md-3 text-center\">\n";
echo "                    <img class=\"rounded-circle reviewer\" src=\"images/davidPic.png\">\n";
echo "                    <div class=\"caption\">\n";
echo "                        <small>By <a href=\"images/davidPic.png\"> David</a></small>\n";
echo "                        \n";
echo "                    </div>\n";
echo "                    \n";
echo "                </div>\n";
echo "                <div class=\"col-md-9\">\n";
echo "                    <h4>".$row['name']."</h4>\n";
echo "                    <p class=\"review-text\">".$row['feedback']." </p>\n";
echo "                    \n";
echo "                    <small class=\"review-date\"></small>\n";
echo "                </div>                          \n";
echo "            </div>  \n";
echo "        </div>\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the class you use for each card

Instead of `.col-lg-4`, you can change  it  `.col-sm-4`

For example,  `<div class="col-sm-4">`

**See example below:**

```css
.blank-section {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 15PX;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  border-radius: .25rem;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
   <?php 
      $result = <your query>; 

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
                         $event = new Event($row);
                          $today = date("Y-m-d");   
                if($event->status == 'published' and $event->date >= $today){
               // output
      ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card">
                image
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">
                        title
                    </h4>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        content
                    </p>
                    <a href="events_page.php" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</a> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```